# My servo is misbehaving

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I have been trying to get my 9g tower pro servo to work and no matter what i do nothing happens. I connected the servo to the arduino with the red wire to 5v, brown to ground and orange to pin 6.

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo;

void setup(){
myServo.attach(6);
}

void loop() {
myServo.write(0);
delay(1000);
myServo.write(60);
}
```

I have been using this code to test it.
Another weird occurrence is when i disconnect the servo it sometimes start moving very slowly even though it has now power. I dont think the Uno is broken as other projects work fine on there, are my servos fried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your drawing too much current from the Arduino 5v rail.

Try connecting the servo to it's own 5v source with of course a common ground with the Arduino.

Comment: I tried connecting it to a 9v and it did not work, would the results be any different with 5v?

Comment: You connected the servo to 9v ?

Comment: yes i connected it to a 9v and the ground to the arduino

Comment: Is your servo motor 9v tolerant ?

Comment: I will look into that and test it with some smaller batterys.

Comment: I think i have broken my servos as i did use 9vs for a long time and they are only meant for 3 - 7.2v (according to the amazon page).

Comment: I tested another servo i had - not one of the ones i have ever used before and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem. There is no delay at the end of the loop. So it runs `myServo.write(0)` then pauses for one second then runs `myServo.write(60)` immediately afterwards it starts the loop over and runs `myServo.write(0)` this happens before the servo has time to move.

To fix this add a delay at the end of the loop.

Try:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo;

void setup(){
myServo.attach(6);
}

void loop() {
myServo.write(0);
delay(1000);
myServo.write(60);
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything as i do not think it is to do with the code, even if i put `myServo.write(50)` in `void setup` the servo would do nothing.

Comment: Did you try the program? When you put myServo.write(50) in the void setup was there code in the loop? There is no delay in between the setup and loop. Try: void setup(){myServo.attach(6) myServo.write(50)} void loop(){}